# How to combine foreach and json_decode in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have an simple JSON file (KironDevCoder.json) :

```
{
  "username":"KironDevCoder",
  "password":"5UD2537AD00FB1E4B3361ABAA593C860738G6K1E828E6C88417C202BF98A1FDD8E56F71B707491U",
  "rank":"Admin"
}
```

When I do

```
$jsonCode = json_decode(file_get_contents("KironDevCoder.json"))
foreach ($jsonCode as $x) {
  echo $x."<br>";
}
```

But then I get:

```
KironDevCoder
5UD2537AD00FB1E4B3361ABAA593C860738G6K1E828E6C88417C202BF98A1FDD8E56F71B707491U
Admin
```

But how do I then get:

```
username
password
rank
```

I know that it isn't needed for this example, but I have the same problem with an file where it is needed.

Comment: `foreach ($jsonCode as $key => $x) { }` ... add the $key and you can use it inside the foreach.

Comment: Thanks for this solution

Comment: Or `foreach (array_keys($jsonCode) as $x) {}`

Comment: Accept BenM's answer when you get the chance. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: @AbraCadaver seems a bit excessive to add another function call when we can do it straight through the data structure?

Comment: @BenM: That's why I didn't post it as an answer. But now they know about `array_keys`.

Answer (score 6):

`foreach` can loop over the key and value of an associative array:

```
foreach( $jsonCode as $k => $v )
```

Given the above example, `$k` will hold the key of your JSON structure (i.e. `username`, `password`, etc.) and `$v` will hold the actual value (`KironDevCoder`, etc.). So you can loop through as follows:

```
foreach( $jsonCode as $k => $v )
{
    echo $k.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Still won't work if you look at his code. he wont have the associative keys, he'll get numeric ones. See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: `mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = FALSE [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )`

Comment: Not true, you're looking at the wrong part of the manual. PHP is able to loop over objects using `foreach`: https://eval.in/1039898

Comment: my vote is locked? wtf? you need to edit it before i can change it?

Comment: Well ... the OP also forgot a semicolon on the end, so his code wouldn't even work at all... if we are being nitpicky ;) But since he said "*But then I get*", with values, one can assume he json_decoded ok, and has the semicolon in place, and his example code on SO is just partial. All he needs is the $k part, which he already confirmed as working and thanked everyone.

Comment: i edited you myself and added a space, your vote is back up now! Thanks for pointing out it was a stdClass and not a numeric array!